# Testing a code running on multiple instances(PROD like behaviour)

Tags: java, multithreading, multiple-instances

As we know it is possible for 2 or more instances of same application/component to be deployed on production. I have written a code for generating unique session id using UUId, what is the guarantee that the UUID generation would not be same in both instance.

All i want is a way to test this with 2 instances of the application/component running parallely(how it is in PROD env), and testing the output of a piece of code in both the instances.

I generate the UUID this way:

```
HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
sessionId = session.getId();
// generate random unique ID 
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
// get client IP address 
String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr(); 
//Concat all to get unique id 
sessionId = sessionId.concat("" + uniqueID + "" + ipAddr + "_" + System.nanoTime() + "");
```

Comment: Couldn't you just create two instances of your UUID generator in a test and see if it generates different UUIDs? Why is it necessary to test that in a fully blown environment?

Comment: @cmoetzing , calling two instances in a test would execute the UUID generator 1 and 2 sequentially. I want to test that if request1 hits instace 1 and request2 hits instance 2 what are the chances that both instances are not generating UUID in same fashion and they are not same after all

Comment: How does your UUID generation work? It does not really matter if you call them sequentially if the precondition your UUID generator depends on is controlled by you. For example: your application counts how many users visited your application. It takes that number and appends the node name and uses that string as UUID. Now you only need to instantiate both UUID generators with the same number of users and a different node name each and you can run your test. They will yield the correct results even if called after one another.

Comment: @cmoetzing here is my code, I am generating unique session id as below :HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
      sessionId = session.getId();
      // generate random unique ID
      String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      // get client IP address
      String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
          .getRequest()
          .getRemoteAddr();
     //Concat all to get unique id
      sessionId = sessionId.concat("_" + uniqueID + "_" + ipAddr + "_" + System.nanoTime() + "");

Comment: How about using odd ids on one instance and even ids on the other instance?

Comment: @memo, the issue is how to test it, perhaps this one works just fine too, if not i can do as u suggest.

Comment: Why do you think that UUID generation is not enough? According to the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) it already contains the time (so `System.nanoTime()` is redundant?) and it contains a hardware specific part (which is probably more unique than `ipAddr`?). So in the end you have basically the same as UUID. I would not test UUID as it is provided with the JDK and you don't test other JDK stuff either. If you insist on testing I would still instantiate the id generator component twice and mock the time and ip parts.

Comment: @cmoetzing `UUID.RandomUUID()` generates a type 4 UUID. Type 4 UUIDs don't include time. Re-read that RFC if you wish, it's specified there, and the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) say it's type 4.

Comment: @ErikA Good point. Still, I do not see the point in extending the UUID concept. If type 4 is not good enough, quote *Distributed applications generating UUIDs at a variety of hosts must
   be willing to rely on the random number source at all hosts.  If this
   is not feasible, the namespace variant should be used.*, use type 3 which is available as `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes()` right?

Comment: Well, the whole question is silly imo, see [Wikipedia on UUID collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions). In my experience, the chance of collisions on non-type 4 UUIDs is a lot bigger because the programmer can make mistakes, and the odds of that happening is a lot greater than the odds of a type 4 UUID causing a collision. In theory you can get collisions with type 4 UUIDs, in practice not so much.

Comment: I was able to test it by deploying executable jars in both the instances to verify unique id generation, Thanks all.